# How to generate random numbers in Agda

Tags: random, agda

I need to generate a simple random number in **Agda**.

I tried googling phrases like 'random number agda' but couldn't find any working code.

In **Haskell** the code would be

```
    import System.Random

main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- num :: Float
    num <- randomIO :: IO Float
    -- This "extracts" the float from IO Float and binds it to the name num
    print $ num
```

outputs would be

```
0.7665119
```

or

```
0.43071353
```

What Agda code would achieve the same results (if it's possible)?

Working code would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest route is probably to postulate the existence of such a primitive and then to explain to Agda how to compile it by using a `COMPILE` pragma.

```
open import Agda.Builtin.Float
import IO.Primitive as Prim
open import IO

random : IO Float
random = lift primRandom where

 postulate primRandom : Prim.IO Float
 {-# FOREIGN GHC import qualified System.Random as Random #-}
 {-# COMPILE GHC primRandom = Random.randomIO #-}

open import Codata.Musical.Notation
open import Function

main : Prim.IO _
main = run $
  ♯ random >>= λ f → ♯ putStrLn (primShowFloat f)
```

I've included a `main` so that you can compile this file (using `agda -c FILENAME`) and run it to see that you indeed get random floats.

Comment: I'm sure your solution works for some users, but I get this error message imgur.com/a/FOMR0V9 any ideas how to get it to compile?

Comment: It's a bug in the stdlib (https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/issues/348); you need to upgrade

Comment: awesome! how do I upgrade?

Comment: Depends on how you installed the library. You need to get version 0.17 or newer (cf. here https://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Libraries.StandardLibrary for a list of compatible versions of Agda for each released version of the stdlib)